# Allow normal users to install exe or msi file on window server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I am met with a situation in which I am forced to give users the right to install .exe and .msi files without them being administrators. Is there any way that this might be achieved?

Comment: What's the specific installer need to do?  A lot of installers touch places where, with access, you could seriously break the machine; hence, the typical need for administrator rights.

Comment: Why would "normal users" be installing things on your server?

Answer (score 3):

If the applications you want to permit them to install isn't too invasive, then you should be able to get away by granting full control on these locations.  If they have to install a driver, then you need to grant administrative access.

- %ProgramData%
- %ProgramFiles%
- %ProgramFiles(x86)%
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE

But some applications are not going to limit themselves to those locations so you will probably have to just give up and Grant administrator access.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the domain's administrator, give [sudowin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sudowin/) a try and see if it meets your needs.